# Google Maps API - how to set center and zoom for current marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

When I initialize google maps in my app, I do something like this:

```
var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.729001, -94.902342),
  zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
setUpMarker(map);
```

Which works, however, I would need to set up the center of the map and zoom for the specific marker that is created by the function `setUpMarker`.

I've tried inside the `setUpMarker` function to do this:

```
fromMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  center: fromLatlng,
  zoom: 5,
  map: map,
  title: "Here"
});
```

But it didn't help. Thus, how do achieve of this effect?

Thank you guys for help.

Comment: A [google.maps.Marker object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) doesn't have those options.  If you want to change the center and the zoom of the [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) you need to call the setCenter and setZoom options on your map.

Comment: Where does fromLatlng come from in your setupMarker function?

Answer (score 10):

The map object has setZoom() and setCenter() functions for the same. Refer to:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents

Comment: Thank you. The event in the `addListener` function is set up on the `click` value. When the marker is clicked, then the map is zoomed and centered. But I would need it automatically, when the map is loaded, I would need to apply on the marker `setZoom()` and `setCenter()`, so after the map would loaded, the marker would be automatically zoomed and centered. Is there any way to do that? Thank you

Comment: Don't keep it in the listener. Just declare the map and your marker and write the setZoom() setCenter() statements after that. You don't need to literally copy the example. Just see how it works.